# how to create a variable in jquery slick

Tags: jquery

I want to assign a value but it doesnt appear to work not sure what is wrong

```
$('#ProductSelect-option-Color-ForestGreen+label').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                slideIndex = $('.pthumbnail').parseInt('1');               
               $( '.slick-slider' ).slickGoTo(slideIndex);
             });
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you post a code snippet with what you expect at the output?

Comment: `parseInt` is a javascript function not jquery. It does not work like `$('.pthumbnail').parseInt('1')`. Try `slideIndex = parseInt('1');`

Comment: @ahmad i just want to pass value

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ProductSelect-option-Color-ForestGreen+label').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $slideIndex = $('.pthumbnail').parseInt('1');               
               $( '.slick-slider' ).slickGoTo($slideIndex);
});
```

Does that work? If not, something is wrong with your functions. Try testing them with normal numbers first (e.g. 1, 5, 10). Also adding all the code would be helpful